# Why does not this callback function cause race condition?

Tags: jquery, node.js, callback

I don't understand why the following code does not cause potential race condition. It looks like `count` and `totalBytes` are variables that can be accessed by multiple callback functions and I felt `count--` and `totalBytes += stats.size` might cause racing because you can't guarantee the orders of the callback functions passed to `fs.stat()` (as it's an IO operation).

```
var fs = require('fs');

var count = 0,
    totalBytes = 0;

function calculateByteSize() {
    fs.readdir(".", function (err, filenames) {
        var i;
        count = filenames.length;

        for (i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
            fs.stat("./" + filenames[i], function (err, stats) {
                totalBytes += stats.size;
                count--;
                if (count === 0) {
                    console.log(totalBytes);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

calculateByteSize();
```

Comment: Why would the order of the callbacks affect the outcome? All you're doing is adding and subtracting. Just like if you changed the values around that  you were adding in a Math equation, you'd still get the same result.

Comment: what do you mean by racing? count is a constant in a directory

Comment: agreeing totally with @adam0101 comments. you need to explain what do you mean by racing  with respect to your snippet. your end result will be the same irrespective of the way the callbacks are fired

Comment: My guess based on J Morris's answer is that chen thought JS supported multithreading, but chen please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript has only one thread, therefore only one callback could be modifying `count` at a time. Order of callbacks, however, is not guaranteed.

Comment: Hmm, apparently web workers can be multi-threaded, so it may depend on how the code is getting executed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh549259.aspx

Comment: @adam0101 - But even if this code was in a webWorker, it is all in one webWorker and there's only one JS thread per webWorker so there's still no race condition.   And, this is nodejs code and there are no webWorkers in nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

If you had reached the count over async function, yes there had been race condition here. But your function is sync, it means that your function is atomic. Due to this no race condition here. If you had used async function here, despite single thread, due to context switching in the event loop, race condition had taken place.